# Why my nodejs app's session is expiring within 40 seconds on windows server

Tags: asp.net, node.js, express, session-state

I have deployed my application in the windows server it's working fine in the local machine i have tried in three different local machines it's working fine. The server is of .net hosting and the hosting company have the feature to enable nodejs applications that i already enabled

**The code that i am using to check session before any action is**

```
// middleware function to check for logged-in users
  var sessionChecker = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
      next();
    } else {
     res.redirect("/")
    }    
  };
```

Application destroys the session within 40 seconds i have asked the hosting company they are saying my application is taking more then 1G memory due to which it recycles so the session destroys and also gave these log messages that i am unable to understand

```
9/11/2018 11:05:54 pm a worker process with process id of '3820' serving 
application pool has requested a recycle because 
it reached its virtual memory limit. 

9/11/2018 11:04:54 pm a worker process with process id of '9580' serving 
application pool has requested a recycle because 
it reached its virtual memory limit.

9/11/2018 11:03:54 pm a worker process with process id of '1720' serving 
application pool has requested a recycle because 
it reached its virtual memory limit.
```

After that i debuged my application on local machine in chrome dev tools here it's not taking more then 30 MB Memory even for one time.I have attached an image of it below

[image: As on the left side it's only taking 24 to 26 MB memory]

Comment: Is your middleware function somehow attached to your "/" route on the hosting server? That would cause an infinite loop which would max out your memory.

Comment: @Prodigle I agree most likely scenario.

Comment: No i dont have middleware on "/" is there any method through which i debug my whole app in local enviroment